# Architecture to be able to have a lot of SQL calls on the same tables for a workflow execution

Tags: postgresql, architecture, workflow

We have a project where we let users execute workflows based on a selection of steps.
Basically each step is linked to an execution and an execution can be linked to one or multiple executionData (the data created or updated during that execution for that step, a blob in postgres).

Today, we execute this through a queuing mechanism where executions are created in queues and workers do the executions and create the next job in the queue.

But this architecture and our implementation make our postgres database slow as when multiple jobs are scheduled at the same time:

- We are basically always creating and reading from the execution table (we create the execution to be scheduled, we read the execution when starting the job, we update the status when the job is finished)
- We are basically always creating and reading from the executionData table (we add and update executionData during executions)

We have the following issues:

- Our executionData table is growing very fast and it's almost impossible to remove rows as there are constantly locks on the table => what could we do to avoid that ? Postgres a good usage for that kind of data ?
- Our execution table is growing as well very fast and it impacts the overall execution as to be able to execute we need to create, read & update execution. Delete of rows is as well almost impossible ... => what could we do to improve this ? Usage of historical table ? Suggestions ?
- We need to perform statistics on the total executions executed & data saved, this is as well requested on the above table which slows  down the process

We use RDS on AWS for our Postgres database.
Thanks for your insights!

Comment: I'm afraid you haven't provided any information that would let someone help. You don't provide details of the table structures, queries, plans, source of these locks or details of where the bottleneck is (CPU, network, disk, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Try going for a faster database architecture.  Your use-case seems well optimized for a DynamoDB architecture for your executions.  You can get O(1) performance, and the blob-storage can fit right into the record as long as you can keep it under 256K.